# How to dynamically change axis from linear to logarithmic in HighChart

Tags: charts, highcharts, logarithm

I want to dynamically change axis from **linear** to **logarithmic** and vice versa in HighCharts. Please see this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/ZCecV/).

```
yAxis: {
    //linear
    type: 'logarithmic',
    minorTickInterval: 0.1
},
```

There is a [type: String](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.type) in api For initial declarative chart setup. I want to dynamically change to logarithmic/linear back and forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `axis.update`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCecV/1/ (docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update() )