# Change Highcharts axis dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm looking to change the yAxis type from "logarithmic" to "linear" dynamically through the API. this will NOT be inside of an event tied to the graph

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You need to present code here, not a requirement list and then ask us to build it for you.

Comment: any way see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change axis from linear to logarithmic in HighChart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324284/how-to-dynamically-change-axis-from-linear-to-logarithmic-in-highchart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the axis.update method from highcharts documentation. this method helps you in updating the axis options.

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({
   type: types[type]
});
```

here is an example for you  http://jsfiddle.net/7h2Vg/

hope this will be useful.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update()

Comment: thanks so much! i was searching for the right api call forever!